# How to create a macro or code snippet that will extract a method's signature for logging?

Tags: .net, vb.net, logging

In my code I have many lines like the following:

```
Public Sub BackupSQLExpressDatabase(databaseName As String, 
                              Optional backupFolder As String = Nothing)
#If DEBUG Then
    Logger.Trace("Enter; databaseName={0}, backupFolder={1}",
                  databaseName, backupFolder)
#End If
```

Typing in the logging information is quite tedious. I see how I can remedy the situation partially with code snippets, but does a tool exist that will add this information to my methods automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [aspect oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416880/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-sharp). To make long story short, it allows you to append logical pieces to every method that matches certain criteria. Often used for logging, security, unified transaction management etc. So you end up writing code once, specify how wiring should work, and the framework does the rest for you.

- [What is the best implementation for AOP in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net)

Out of those listed, [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/products) seems to be a good candidate to start one's research.

To get method signature, see this answer:

- [Actual Method Signature Using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435532/actual-method-signature-using-reflection)

Comment: I installed PostsharpExpress and wroote my first two Aspects! Thanks a lot.